# Escape special characters in Solr query while searching on fields?

Tags: solr, lucene

Solr Query: `fooField:foovalue OR barField:barValue`

This query can be query override from browser which risks potential injection attacks. But escaping special characters like `:` and whitespace doesn't returns result as expected.

Is there a way to escape the query and search on solr fields to get desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `edismax` query handler is made for situations like this - if you don't want the user to be able to attach field names themselves, use `qf` to tell Solr which fields it should search, then escape the query properly and send it in the `q` parameter as raw text.

If you *do* want to search different values in different fields, you'll have to escape each value and prefix it with the field name as you've shown.

Comment: `dismax` supports `qf` too

Comment: @EricLavault That is correct, but there is not really any reasons for using dismax instead of edismax these days.

Comment: @MatsLindh can you give an example query for "Search different values in different fields"  ?

Comment: `field1:this\ is\ an\ escaped\ query OR field2:this\ as\ well\:\ see`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent injection attack in this context, considering the query string could be overridden, you need to filter user input accordingly :

- A web server should display a search form which has to be validated before making a Solr request from it. This form, no matter the input(s) in the UI, should not take a query string to pass directly to Solr once submitted, but rather multiple field inputs to be parsed and checked :

  ```
  ?fieldA=terms&fieldb=otherterms
  ```
- Users should not be able to search into arbitrary field names : in a validation handler, you need to check if `fieldname` is actually searchable. That means for example that if  `[fieldA, fieldB, fieldC]` are the only fields in which users can legitimately make a query, anything but these fields should be discarded :

  ```
  ?fieldA=terms&inject:ed=willBeDiscarded
  ```

If you need users to be able to search different values in different fields - if you cannot use `qf` - UI may help to distinguish between colon in `field:<terms>` and colon in `field:<termsContainingColon>`, in this case you may want to have one input text by searchable fields, so that user input is purely restricted to the value of each field.

Answer (score 0):

To escape values Solrj has the useful method [`ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars()`](https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_11_2/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#escapeQueryChars-java.lang.String-). Though you can use it only on the right side (value) of the field:value query.